C++ Convert PUNICODE_STRING to char
Why are strings in C++ so freakin' complicated?!?!
OK, let's back up a bit and I'll explain what's going on.
I am in the process of moving all of the scripts we use for accounts and such off of UMRA (which is going the way of the Dodo) to PowerShell. I had to find a way to capture password changes so they can be synced out to other systems, and was delighted when I found out that I could write my own password filter DLL to do the trick.
Now, I've played around with a number of programming languages, and I'm sure C++ was in there somewhere, so even though it's been years since I've worked with C++ I figured that, with a little help from Google, I should be able to write something that triggers a PowerShell scrip that can take care of the rest.
When I looked up the best way to trigger a PowerShell script, I found the system() command. Looks simple enough. I see that it takes a char string, and the DLL is getting a PUNICODE_STRING, but it shouldn't be a problem to convert one string to another... right?
So I decided to start with a very simple DLL that just passes everything it gets to a simple PowerShell script as command line arguments (which I tested with CMD to make sure that would work). Then, once I get that working, I plan to add some actual password filtering and maybe encrypting the password (in case the system() command is logged somewhere) before passing it to PS.
That was 2 weeks ago, and I can't even figure out how to translate PUNICODE_STRING to the char type that system() expects. And I've tried so many things, I can't remember them all. Yesterday I spent some time re-trying some of the ones I could remember, so I could document them here.
I'm working in Visual Studio 2022, on Windows Server 2016.
In the first code example, I have shown the entire code, but in subsequent examples I have commented out DllMain, InitializeChangeNotify, and PasswordFilter to save room in this post.
I would also like to point out that I haven't tried compiling anything yet, I'm trying to get the code to a point where the debugger is happy first. So I have included the debugger errors as comments on the line that triggered them.
OK, my first attempt was to pack all of the text and variables into the system() command... which didn't work, so I started trying to make a char variable that I could pass to system().
#include "pch.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SubAuth.h>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <winternl.h>
#include <string.h>

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

BOOLEAN __stdcall InitializeChangeNotify(void)
{
    return TRUE;
}

NTSTATUS __stdcall PasswordChangeNotify(PUNICODE_STRING UserName, ULONG RelativeId, PUNICODE_STRING NewPassword)
{

    char PSCommand[] = "start powershell.exe SD60PWS.ps1 -Section 'ChangeNotify' -UserName ";
    strcat(PSCommand, UserName); //Error - argument of type "PUNICODE_STRING" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *"
    //strcat(PSCommand, " -RelativeId ");
    //strcat(PSCommand, RelativeId);
    //strcat(PSCommand, " -NewPassword ");
    //strcat(PSCommand, NewPassword);
    system(PSCommand);
    return 0;
}

BOOLEAN __stdcall PasswordFilter(PUNICODE_STRING AccountName, PUNICODE_STRING FullName, PUNICODE_STRING Password, BOOLEAN SetOperation)
{
    return 1;
}

So I started Googling and found a reference to using RtlUnicodeStringToAnsiString() to do the conversion. Of course they didn't say how so I had to do a bunch more searching and eventually came up with this...
#include "pch.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SubAuth.h>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <winternl.h>
#include <string.h>

//DllMain and InitializeChangeNotify

NTSTATUS __stdcall PasswordChangeNotify(PUNICODE_STRING UserName, ULONG RelativeId, PUNICODE_STRING NewPassword)
{
    ANSI_STRING ConvUserName;
    RtlUnicodeStringToAnsiString(&ConvUserName, UserName, TRUE);
    //Note: the example I found had an & in front of both variables, but the debugger didn't like that
    // So I took them both away, and it didn't like that either. But the debugger was OK with this.

    char PSCommand[] = "start powershell.exe SD60PWS.ps1 -Section 'ChangeNotify' -UserName ";
    strcat(PSCommand, ConvUserName); //Error - no suitable conversion function from "ANSI_STRING" to "const char *"
    //strcat(PSCommand, " -RelativeId ");
    //strcat(PSCommand, RelativeId);
    //strcat(PSCommand, " -NewPassword ");
    //strcat(PSCommand, NewPassword);
    system(PSCommand);
    return 0;
}

//PasswordFilter

In my poking around on the interweb, I came across this excellent blog 'The Complete Guide to C++ Strings, Part I and Part II' by Michael Dunn. Very informative... but also melted my brain.
One thing I found in it that I thought I should try was ATL conversion macros.
#include "pch.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SubAuth.h>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <winternl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <atlconv.h>

//DllMain and InitializeChangeNotify

NTSTATUS __stdcall PasswordChangeNotify(PUNICODE_STRING UserName, ULONG RelativeId, PUNICODE_STRING NewPassword)
{
    USES_CONVERSION;
    using std::string;

    string ConvUserName;
    ConvUserName = W2CA(UserName); //Error - a value of type "PUNICODE_STRING" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "LPCWSTR"

    char PSCommand[] = "start powershell.exe SD60PWS.ps1 -Section 'ChangeNotify' -UserName ";
    strcat(PSCommand, ConvUserName); //Error - no suitable conversion function from "std::string" to "const char *" exists
    //strcat(PSCommand, " -RelativeId ");
    //strcat(PSCommand, RelativeId);
    //strcat(PSCommand, " -NewPassword ");
    //strcat(PSCommand, NewPassword);
    system(PSCommand);
    return 0;
}

//PasswordFilter

After that, I went back to Microsoft's post How to: Convert Between Various String Types. I though I'd picked up enough to be able to try their suggestion. I think I copied (and personalized) it all correctly, maybe I missed something?
#include "pch.h"
#include "atlbase.h"
#include "atlstr.h"
#include "comutil.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SubAuth.h>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <winternl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <atlconv.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace System; //Error - name must be a namespace name

//DllMain and InitializeChangeNotify

NTSTATUS __stdcall PasswordChangeNotify(PUNICODE_STRING UserName, ULONG RelativeId, PUNICODE_STRING NewPassword)
{
    
    size_t origsize = wcslen(UserName) + 1; //Error - argument of type "PUNICODE_STRING" is incompatible with parameter of type "const wchar_t *"
    size_t convertedChars = 0;
    char strConcat[] = " (char *)";
    size_t strConcatsize = (strlen(strConcat) + 1) * 2;
    const size_t newsize = origsize * 2;
    char* ConvUserName = new char[newsize + strConcatsize];
    wcstombs_s(&convertedChars, ConvUserName, newsize, UserName, _TRUNCATE); //Error - no instance of overloaded function "wcstombs_s" matches the argument list
    _mbscat_s((unsigned char*)ConvUserName, newsize + strConcatsize, (unsigned char*)strConcat);

    char PSCommand[] = "start powershell.exe SD60PWS.ps1 -Section 'ChangeNotify' -UserName ";
    strcat(PSCommand, ConvUserName);
    //strcat(PSCommand, " -RelativeId ");
    //strcat(PSCommand, RelativeId);
    //strcat(PSCommand, " -NewPassword ");
    //strcat(PSCommand, NewPassword);
    system(PSCommand);
    return 0;
}

//PasswordFilter

Lastly, while searching Stack Overflow specifically (before asking this question) I came across this post that wasn't exactly what I was looking for, but they were passing the PUNICODE_STRING to a function that accepted it as a char* variable. So I figured I'd give that a try.
#include "pch.h"
#include "atlbase.h"
#include "atlstr.h"
#include "comutil.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SubAuth.h>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <winternl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <atlconv.h>

using namespace std;

//DllMain and InitializeChangeNotify

NTSTATUS __stdcall PasswordChangeNotify(PUNICODE_STRING UserName, ULONG RelativeId, PUNICODE_STRING NewPassword)
{
    WriteToPowerShell("ChangeNotify", UserName, NewPassword); //Error - argument of type "PUNICODE_STRING" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *"
    
    return 0;
}

//PasswordFilter

void WriteToPowerShell(const char* PSSection, const char* PSUserName, const char* PSPassWord)
{
    char PSCommand[] = "start powershell.exe SD60PWS.ps1 -Section ";
    strcat(PSCommand, PSSection);
    strcat(PSCommand, " -UserName ");
    strcat(PSCommand, PSUserName);
    strcat(PSCommand, " -NewPassword ");
    strcat(PSCommand, PSPassWord);
    system(PSCommand);
}

One last note. I know I probably have a lot of #includes that I don't need and things like that. That's because every time I tried something I would add any that I needed for that test, but I didn't bother removing them after. I plan to comment them out one-by-one later, and discard the ones that don't cause an error, and uncomment the ones that do.
I hope someone out there can help. And I hope that all of these failures weren't just because I didn't know I needed to #include <this> or using namespace that.
Alternately, if there's some other way to trigger the PowerShell script that accepts PUNICODE_STRING, that would be helpful too.
Thank you.

Why are strings in C++ so freakin' complicated?!?! -- std::string and std::wstring are quite simple.  What you are encountering are string encoding issues, and the C++ standard has no say on this.

First of all, that strcat will cause an illegal memory access. It will try to write past the contents of the PSCommand buffer since it appends to the destination.
Second, UNICODE_STRING is defined as a struct with a wchar_t* Buffer and a size field. You can construct an std::wstring using that, convert it to std::string and pass the result of std::string::c_str() to the system function.

Your first PasswordChangeNotify leaks memory.  Your second PasswordChangeNotify writes beyond the character buffer (buffer overflow).  I suggest that you do everything using just std::string and/or std::wstring -- absolutely no char arrays, no calls to new[], etc..

I get that you want to rant, but rants don't make good questions. Please read [ask] and [mre].

Don't blame C++. That's all Microsoft cruft.


I can't even figure out how to translate PUNICODE_STRING to the char type that system() expects.

UNICODE_STRING contains a wchar_t* string pointer.
You can convert a wchar_t* string to a char* string using the Win32 WideCharToMultiByte() function.  Or, you can use the (deprecated) std::wstring_convert class, or wcsrtombs().  Or, an equivalent 3rd party library, like ICU (which is now built-in to Windows 10 and later).  There are MANY different ways (and MANY answered questions on StackOverflow) related to string conversions.

Alternately, if there's some other way to trigger the PowerShell script that accepts PUNICODE_STRING, that would be helpful too.

Rather than using system() at all, you can instead use the Win32 CreateProcessW() function (which is what system() calls internally). system() merely runs "cmd.exe /C <command>". In this case, your <command> is using start to run PowerShell.exe. You can run PowerShell.exe directly with CreateProcessW() using a wchar_t* string, eg:
NTSTATUS __stdcall PasswordChangeNotify(PUNICODE_STRING UserName, ULONG RelativeId, PUNICODE_STRING NewPassword)
{
    std::wstring PSCommand = L"powershell.exe SD60PWS.ps1 -Section 'ChangeNotify' -UserName ";
    PSCommand.append(UserName->Buffer, UserName->Length / sizeof(WCHAR));

    //PSCommand += L" -RelativeId ";
    //PSCommand += std::to_wstring(RelativeId);
    //PSCommand += L" -NewPassword ";
    //PSCommand.append(NewPassword->Buffer, NewPassword->Length / sizeof(WCHAR));

    STARTUPINFOW si = {};
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    // setup any parameters of si as needed...

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {};

    if (CreateProcessW(nullptr, PSCommand.data(), nullptr, nullptr, FALSE, 0, nullptr, nullptr, &si, &pi))
    {
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    }

    return 0;
}


UserName->Length is size in bytes, so in characters  this will be UserName->Length / sizeof(WCHAR). from another side, if i not mistake, wstring::append use size in characters . so probably PSCommand.append(UserName->Buffer, UserName->Length / sizeof(wchar_t));

why simply not use _snwprintf here (single call in loop) for format cmd line

@RbMm You could, but that requires a pre-allocated buffer. And since the question is tagged C++, using std::wstring made more sense for example's sake.

but that requires a pre-allocated buffer, no, possible do this in another way. show it in self answer just for demo of another way

@RbMm you are allocating a buffer for _snwprintf, so how is my statement "requires a pre-allocated buffer" wrong? Just because you are allocating it locally on the stack instead of dynamically doesn't change that. Not to mention that use of alloca() is discouraged anyway.

Maybe i wrong understand what mean pre-allocated buffer . In any case need allocate buffer for format string here. In case std::wstring too, simply this done is internal here. I only show how possible format string . Use alloca ( if we assume relative small size of string ) or _malloca not principal here

at first of course you need use here not system but CreateProcessW () for start new process. about string manipulations - one simply way - use c style format functions. here _snwprintf most suitable and use %wZ format for PUNICODE_STRING. example:
NTSTATUS NTAPI PasswordChangeNotify(PUNICODE_STRING UserName, ULONG RelativeId, PUNICODE_STRING NewPassword)
{
    int len = 0;
    PWSTR pszCmdLine = 0;

    while (0 < (len = _snwprintf(pszCmdLine, len, 
        L"powershell.exe SD60PWS.ps1 -Section 'ChangeNotify' @%x@%wZ@%wZ",
        RelativeId, UserName, NewPassword)))
    {
        if (pszCmdLine)
        {
            STARTUPINFO si { sizeof(si) };
            PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
            if (CreateProcessW(0, pszCmdLine, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &si, &pi))
            {
                CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
                CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
            }
            break;
        }

        pszCmdLine = (PWSTR)alloca(++len * sizeof(WCHAR));
    }

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

